# Coroutine execute code during WaitForSeconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm spawning prefabs and use a coroutine but I can see a random delay or spaces gap between prefab cause of the function I run before yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.3f);

```
IEnumerator SpawnObject()
{
    while (true)
    {
        GameObject screenShape = (GameObject)Instantiate(screenlines, new Vector3(ShapespawnerObjPos.transform.localPosition.x, shapeposition[GetFirstIndexlistofIntShapePosition()], ShapespawnerObjPos.transform.localPosition.z), transform.rotation);

        //function get random number with checking called here 

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.3f);
    }
}
```

What I'm planning to do is execute the function get random number with checking during WaitForSeconds() not before it to avoid random spaces gap between prefab.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following. What does checking a random number have to do with the `WaitForSeconds`?

Comment: I just wanted to run a function during the waiting period of coroutine

Comment: That is precisely how Waits *do not* work. You might be able to finagle your way around it using a `WaitWhile` or `WaitUntil` using a lambda anonymous function, then you'd have to count time manually.

Comment: Why not write the function into another coroutine and start that coroutine before `WaitForSeconds`?

Answer (score 0):

WaitForSeconds stop the execution of that method for the number of seconds you say.
You cannot execute anything during that time, that's what WaitForSeconds try to avoid (execute code).

You should try to complete the code but if the delay is something made out of calculation I suggest you to just create an array/list of generated number in the Start method and use that list instead of calculate it at "runtime"... You can cycle on that list or generate a new one everytime you run out of numbers, you will still avoid to generate multiple instance of that calculation and, that way, you should be able to avoid random delay.

Still, remember that I only saw part of your code so I cannot be sure about the reason of the delay.